# How to correctly setup an interface-only project (and its dependent projects) in NPM?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, import, typescript-typings

I'm facing two issues with a TypeScript project of mine.

Let's say I want to make an **interface-only** TypeScript project named `myproject-api`. I intend to implement the interfaces in two different projects named `myproject-impl1` and `myroject-impl2`. I'm using [Lerna](https://lernajs.io/) to manage those projects as modules in a root project named `myproject`, and all of them were [bootstrapped](https://lernajs.io/#command-bootstrap) as needed (`npm link`). I'm also using `gulp` to transpile the TypeScript source, and the config is very simple as of now.

**Issue 1.** Even with `"types": "dist/main.d.ts"` or `"types": "src/index.ts"` in `package.json`, the implementation module is not able to see the type definitions in `myproject-api`. I also tried to move `myproject-api/src/index.ts` to `myproject-api/index.ts`, to no avail. The compiler just fails with the message **`Cannot find module 'myproject-api'.`**

**Issue 2.** It seems that TypeScript doesn't generate the `.d.ts` file if there's no actual implementation in the `.ts` source files, **unless** I compile the project with `tsc -d --outFile dist/main.js`. In other words, for some reason, if I use my `tsconfig.json` configuration (e.g. `tsc --project tsconfig.json`) the `.js` files are generated, but not the `.d.ts` files.

**P.S.:** I started the project just to flesh out and refine some ideas I had in mind. If anyone has a better setup  for this kind of project layout, please tell me.

---

#### Some more info...

I'm using ES6 imports in all `.ts` projects.

This is my folder layout:

```
.
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── myproject-api
│   |   ├── dist
│   │   ├── gulpfile.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── myproject-impl*
│       ├── dist
│       ├── gulpfile.js
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       │   └── index.ts
│       └── tsconfig.json
└── README.md
```

`packages/myproject-api/src/someClass.ts`:

```
export interface ISomeClass { /* ... */ }
```

`packages/myproject-api/src/index.ts`:

```
export * from "./someClass.ts"
// (repeating this kind of export for all inner modules)
```

`packages/myproject-impl*/src/index.ts`:

```
import { ISomeClass } from "myproject-api"
// ...
```

Gulp config:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

gulp.task("default", ["build"]);

gulp.task("build", function () {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

This is the `tsconfig.json` for all projects:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "amd",
        "strict": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "outFile": "dist/main.js",
        "declaration": true,
        "lib": [
            "es5",
            "es2015.promise",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

System info:

```
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ tsc --version
Version 2.6.2
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ node --version
v9.3.0
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ lerna --version
2.5.1
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ gulp --version
[03:39:24] CLI version 2.0.0
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ npm --version
5.6.0
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ uname -a
Linux sonic 4.14.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 14 21:26:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[flisboac@sonic ~]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    1.4
Distributor ID: Arch
Description:    Arch Linux
Release:    rolling
Codename:   n/a
```

Comment: if intention is `myproject-api` being a pure interface only, why try to transpile it instead just publish ts file as-is as npm pkg, and each impl directly imports it? as it's interface only doesn't have any implementation, consumer won't need to worry about config build for ts source under node_modules.

Comment: The problem is that the import is not working for some reason.

Comment: it may related with consumer side config / or something else - per https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html, it is supported resolution cases. try `tsc --traceResolution` might give answer.

Comment: @OJKwon Indeed, `--traceResolution` helped me figure out. `tsc` only looks at `package.json` if you specify `"moduleResolution": "node"` in `tsconfig.json`, which by default is `"moduleResolution": "classic"`. Visual Studio Code still can't figure out the import for some reason though, but at least I can compile the project via `tsc`. Anyways, do you want to make the answer?

Comment: As a second note, I had to restart VSCode for it to correctly resolve the imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @OJKwon suggested, `--traceResolution` helped me figure out. As per [the documentation for module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), `tsc` only looks at `package.json` if you specify `"moduleResolution": "node"` in `tsconfig.json`, which by default is `"moduleResolution": "classic"`. The use of `index.ts` as a default import pattern is also only used for the `node` resolution.

I also had to restart VSCode for it to correctly resolve the imports.